# android Clicking on Adview not getting to Advertisement page

Tags: android, admob, adview

The AdView is not working on my app since the last 2 days.
Whenever you click on the AdView nothing happens. So I just plugged my mobile phone to my computer and started android studio to realize that the following error is being thrown:
`E/Ads: JS: Uncaught TypeError: e.he is not a function (https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20170227/r20110914/client/ext/m_js_controller.js:1)`
I have no clue how to solve the problem since I haven't touched my code for weeks.

Comment: Sounds like an issue on Google's end. Make sure you're using the latest version of the AdMob SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/download

Comment: The problem was in fact on Google's end. Everything is back to normal.